# Autenticação Java em DataBase gerado pelo Asp.net MVC 5(Gerar passwordhash em Java igual Asp.net MVC 5)

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso Autenticar um usuário criado em automaticamente em asp.net mvc 5 utilizando a linguagem java por Exemplo:

> usuário: fulano
>   password: Ab123456

### Senha gravada no Banco de Dados

```
PasswordHash
ACFCCbS1aKYPrQndKMluPDpLD51m1yh5UDBo49v1m4i44aU9SiCJSnCB16XDXJ5iQQ==

SecurityStamp
905d2faa-ed55-48f0-9d1b-c2d079015329
```

preciso gerar um Hash em Java que seja igual o gerado pela Aplicação Asp.net MVC 5

Comment: Que código está gravando isso em C# (compartilhe conosco)? que tipo de função hash é essa (MD5, SHA, bcrypt, etc)? Quais as características desse algoritmo (tamanho, salt, etc)?

Comment: O Código que gera esse hash esta dentro do .netFramework 4.5.1 na clase UserManager e PasswordHasher do namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity o algoritimo de criptografia esta encapsulado nestas classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que vocês utilizam o `PasswordHasher` padrão do lado do .NET, conforme [esse post do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure) a mágica toda do algoritmo acontece na classe `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` (implementação do algoritmo `PBKDF2` usando `Hmac` baseado em `SHA1`).

O resultado do hash armazenado no banco está em Base 64, dividido da seguinte forma:

- 16 bytes: Salt gerado aleatóriamente
- 32 Bytes: O hash da senha em si.

[Esse artigo](http://galfar.vevb.net/wp/2014/net-and-java-generating-interoperable-aes-key-and-iv/) dá uma ideia de como derivar a chave a partir do Java:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = 
    SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, 
    saltBytes, iterationCount, 256 + 128);
SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

byte[] data = secretKey.getEncoded();
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[256 / 8]; // hash de 32 bytes
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[128 / 8]; // salt de 16 bytes

System.arraycopy(data, 0, keyBytes, 0, 256 / 8);
System.arraycopy(data, 256 / 8, ivBytes, 0, 128 / 8);  

SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
byte[] key = secretKey.getEncoded();
```

Alternativamente você pode buscar uma implementação da classe `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` ([encontrei essa aqui](http://pastebin.com/iReZJ3Vq)).

Finalmente uma vez que você possua uma implementação do algoritmo acima, basta portar a solução de verificação de senhas da [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/664577) (classe [Crypto](http://dotnetinside.com/ru/type/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto/2.0.0.0) do *assembly* *Identity*) que consiste em quebrar o *hash* persistido no banco em *salt* + chave, computar a chave da senha utilizando o *salt* persistido e verificar se a chave computada é igual à persistida. Seguem os passos (não pude testar pois estou sem um compilador).

```
public boolean verifyPassword(String hashedPassword, String plainPassword) {
    // Se o hash é vazio não autentica
    if (hashedPassword == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (plainPassword== null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password should not be null");
    }
    // Extrai os bytes do hash persistido no banco 
    byte[] src = Base64.getDecoder().decode(hashedPassword);
    // Array de 49 bytes, o primeiro byte é vazio
    if (src.length != 0x31 || array[0] != 0) {
       return false;
    }

    // Extrai o salt
    byte[] salt = new byte[0x10];
    System.arraycopy(src, 1, salt, 0, 0x10);
    // Extrai a chave
    byte[] persistedKey = new byte[0x20];
    System.arraycopy(src, 0x11, persistedKey , 0, 0x20);

    // Computa 1000 iteracoes em cima da senha limpa com o salt do banco
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
            plainPassword, salt, 0x3e8); 
    byte[] computedKey = rfc2898DeriveBytes.getBytes(0x20);

    // Se a chave computada for igual a persistida o usuário entrou a senha correta
    return Arrays.equals(persistedKey, computedKey);
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado é Exatamente isso que eu estava procurando!!